# How to check in code into repository with a VSTS task name

Tags: git, azure-devops

Currently we can check in code and link the commit id to a task or a backlog item manually in VSTS.
I would like to check in code directly into a git repository branch by mentioning the task name and the commit details appear automatically in the VSTS task item.

Can anyone let me know if this is possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the work item ID in the commit message.

Ex: A commit message `"Did some stuff #1234"` will link the commit to work item 1234.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still not working, make sure Work item management setting is set to **on**

[image]

This setting is found from Project settings > Repositories > Click repository from "Git repositories" tree and finally click "Options".